# When to use uid and when to use $id in angularfire

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire

> $id The key where this record is stored. The same as obj.$ref().key
>
> To get the id of an item in a $firebaseArray within ng-repeat, call $id on that item.

These two are from the angular fire reference:
https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md

What I understand is if there is firebase object created with :

```
var object = $firebaseObject(objectRef);
```

then I can use uid always.

```
uid : object.uid
```

But I saw examples where the firebase auth user is used with $id.

```
return Auth.$requireSignIn().then(function (firebaseUser) {
                        return Users.getProfile(firebaseUser.uid).$loaded().then(function (profile) {
               **profile.uid or profile.$id here**
```

Also is it possible the object to have uid but not to have $id (obj.$ref().key). Aren't they the same thing? Does the object have to be loaded first with $loaded() to use $id or uid?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two concepts:

- the `object.$id` of an AngularFire object contains the key of that object in the Firebase Database.
- a `firebaseUser.uid` in Firebase terms is the identification of a Firebase Authentication user.

It is common to store your Firebase Authentication users in the database under their `uid`, in which case `user.$id` would be their `uid`. But they are still inherently different things.

```
Users
   uid1
      displayName: "makkasi"
   uid2
      displayName: "Frank van Puffelen"
```

So if you we look at the code snippet you shared:

```
return Auth.$requireSignIn().then(function (firebaseUser) {
    return Users.getProfile(firebaseUser.uid).$loaded().then(function (profile) {
```

The first line requires that the user is signed-in; only then will it execute the next line with the `firebaseUser` that was signed in. This is a regular JavaScript object ([firebase.User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User)), not an AngularFire `$firebaseObject`.

The second line then uses the `firebaseUser.uid` property (the identification of that user) to load the user's profile from the database into an AngularFire `$firebaseObject`. Once that profile is loaded, it executes the third line.

If the users are stored in the database under their `uid`, at this stage `profile.$id` and `firebaseUser.uid` will be the same value.

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely clear. So that's why I don't see other objects (except users) to be used with uid. All other objects have only object.$id.